# Hyper-V, Linux . Can I install mouse and graphic integration?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows-server-2008, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I use windows server 2008r2 with role Hyper-V. The guest system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTC. There is local network between Ubuntu and other machines.

***EDIT***  The main problem for me is that my quest OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTC. As I know, mouse support is not included in the Hyper-V Linux integration components.

> 4.2.2.2. Graphics and mouse integration
>
> In Linux and Solaris guests, VirtualBox graphics and mouse integration
>   goes through the X Window System. VirtualBox can use the X.Org variant
>   of the system (or XFree86 version 4.3 which is identical to the first
>   X.Org release). During the installation process, the X.Org display
>   server will be set up to use the graphics and mouse drivers which come
>   with the Guest Additions.
>
> After installing the Guest Additions into a fresh installation of a
>   supported Linux distribution or Solaris system (many unsupported
>   systems will work correctly too), the guest's graphics mode will
>   change to fit the size of the VirtualBox window on the host when it is
>   resized. You can also ask the guest system to switch to a particular
>   resolution by sending a "video mode hint" using the VBoxManage tool.

How can I achieve graphics and mouse integration with hyper-v and ubuntu?

***Answer for the first part of the question*** Today it is impossible

I have vhd file. Can I create a virtual machine from this file in Virtualbox, work with this OS, then create a virtual machine in Hyper-V when all work will be done?

Comment: The mouse should work without you having to do anything. Exactly how are you opening your connection to the guest?

Comment: The mouse works. The problem is that the mouse works not good. I watch mouse's jerky movement. Also windows move slowly. I do not like it. Such problem was when I used virtualbox without guest additions.

           I open this connection from hyper-v manager. It is the same: c:\Program Files\Hyper-V\vmconnect.exe

Comment: @AmShegar You answered your own question: `As I know, mouse [integration] support is not included in the Hyper-V Linux integration components.` It is not supported, ergo *you can't do it*. If you would like it to be supported, contact Microsoft. As a business, they implement what their customers demand, so if enough people ask for Linux/X11 mouse integration capabilities maybe they'll do it...

Answer (score 2):

If you install the Windows RSAT tools and include the Hyper-V management roles then you can use `c:\Program Files\Hyper-V\vmconnect.exe` to connect to the console of the VM.

Comment: What do you mean? my mouse does not move good, windows move slowly (my quest OS - Ubuntu). I want to connect to this OS by another protocol to solve this problem. Is it real? What do I must install on the ubuntu?

Comment: Also, on the other machines with Windows there are OS Windows Server 2003 and Windows7. How can I find c:\Program Files\Hyper-V\vmconnect.exe ?